# $.getJSON Google Images exibindo resultados incorretos

Tags: javascript

Baseado neste código:

```
function baixarCapa(capa, item) {
   $.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?callback=?", {
       q: '"' + capa + '"',
       v: '1.0'
   }, function(data) {
        var url = data.responseData.results[0].url;
        $('[data-capa=' + item + ']').html('<img src="' + url + '">');
    });
}
```

Eu consigo baixar as imagens de artistas usando a API do Google Images, porem os resultados erram em 50% dos casos e são diferentes de quando eu acesso o site do Google e pesquiso pelo mesmo termo.

[Comportamento do $.getJSON http://img.somdomato.com/imagens/top10.jpg](http://img.somdomato.com/imagens/top10.jpg)

Porque isso acontece? Como posso corrigir este comportamento?
Obrigado.

Comment: Quando VOCÊ pesquisa, existe cache em seu navegador ou até mesmo você está logado em sua conta google, onde existem mecanismos de preferências que vai saber ao certo o que você quer. Experimente abrir uma guia anônima e fazer a pesquisa.

Comment: Sim, mesmo com a guia anônima o primeiro resultado é completamente diferente, e correto.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, como você está passando o valor pro parâmetro `capa`?

Comment: Você acertou em cheio, eu estava buscando Artista - Musica quando o correto era somente Artista!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava buscando artista e musica quando o correto seria só o artista.
Alterei:

```
capa = nome.split('/').pop();
```

Para:

```
capa = nome.split('/').pop().split('-');
```

E use `capa[0]` ao invés de `capa`.

Obrigado a atenção pessoal!
Em especial ao @rrnan